# How to put value in textbox with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have troble with my code. i want put the value to text box but the value not display very well..

```
    for(var i = 0;i<jmlitem;i++){
                        $('.form-item').append("<p>"+u+" - "+
                                              "<input type='text' name='harga["+i+"]'/>"+  <<-- here my text box
                                              "<input type='number' name='jml["+i+"]'/>"+
                                              "<input type='text' name='keterangan["+i+"]'/></p>");
                        $("select").change(function(){
                           var id_item = $(this).find( "option:selected" ).val();
                           $.ajax({
                              type:'POST',
                              url: "{{URL::to('getharga')}}",
                              data: 'id_item='+id_item,
                              dataType:'json',
                              success: function(data){
                                $(this).next("input[type='text']").val(data.harga); //<-- this is not working
console.log(data.harga); //<--display in console
                              }
                            });
                        });
                      }
```

i tried like this but error.. can you help me ? 
thx..

Comment: `but the text boxt cannot run well` What does mean???

Comment: FYI, `this` in success callback is referring to jqXHR object. You should use ajax context option: `context: this,`

Answer (score 0):

Your context is lost in ajax method. use option `context` to set element context in ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
                      type:'POST',
                      url: "{{URL::to('getharga')}}",
                      data: 'id_item='+id_item,
                      context:this,
                      dataType:'json',
                      success: function(data){
                        $(this).next("input[type='text']").val(data.harga); 
                      }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code

```
success: function(data){
                       $(this).next("input[type='text']").val(data.harga); //<-- this is not working
console.log(data.harga); //<--display in console
}
```

**data.harga** contains the data you want to put at some textbox having selector query

```
$(this).next("input[type='text']").val(data.harga);
```

try debugging in console and check the following command.

```
$(this).next("input[type='text']").length
```

if the **length > 0** then only the value will be assigned to the input control. If it is **==0** then you have to change the selector.
I can help you more if you share the html markup.

Hope it helps .....